# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
**HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /reg.jsp at line 24
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /reg.jsp at line 24

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /reg.jsp at line 24

    22: Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
    23: ResultSet rs; 
    24: int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO userinfo" + 
    25:         " (userid, fname, lname, email, pwd)" + 
    26:         " VALUES" + 
    27:         " ('" +  userid+ "'," +

**
```

Table: userinfo

```
Columns:
userid int(11) AI PK 
fname varchar(45) 
lname varchar(45) 
pwd varchar(45) 
email varchar(45)*
```

Web Content

```
WEB_INF
reg.jsp**

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>regjsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="MyApp" >
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
    <%
    String userid=request.getParameter("userid"); 
    String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd"); 
    String fname=request.getParameter("fname"); 
    String lname=request.getParameter("lname"); 
    String email=request.getParameter("email"); 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo",
    "root","mupurili123A"); 
    Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs; 
    int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO userinfo" + 
            " (userid, fname, lname, email, pwd)" + 
            " VALUES" + 
            " ('" +  userid+ "'," + 
               " '"  +  fname + "'," + 
               " '"  +  lname + "'," + 
               " '"  + email + "','" +pwd + "')");
    if (i > 0) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        //response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='login.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        out.print("Registration failed!");
        //response.sendRedirect("index.html");
    }
    %>
    <a href ="Login.html">Login</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Java Resources** 
src

```
package com.srk.pkg;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class Conn {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo",
                    "root","mupurili123A"); 
            Statement st= (Statement) con.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select *from demo");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
            con.close();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Try to use an int value for userId (it's possible that the database is in strict mode so it won't parse a string into an int). Also, try to write a servlet rather than dealing with this ugly scriptlet code.

Comment: Ti-ai pus poza gogosico

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of passing `String` of `userid` which expecting primitive data type `int` in your database is throwing an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request., you can use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert a String to int.

```
String userid=request.getParameter("userid"); 
int id=Integer.parseInt(userid);
```

and in your query replace `userid` by `id` and make sure you have `mysql-connector-java-version.jar` in your `tomcat_dir/lib/`.